# ¿Como imprimir la sucesion de fibonnacci de manera inversa?

Tags: c, bucles, fibonacci

nos han dejado varios programas sobre ciclos para imprimirlos normalmente y tambien de forma inversa
La sucesión de fibonacci es la que mas me ha dado problemas
anexo el codigo

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
int main(){
int a=0,b=1,c,fibo,opc,i;
printf("cuantos numeros de fibonacci necesitas\n");
scanf("%d",&fibo);
printf("que metodo deseas utilizar\n");
printf("1 for\n");
printf("2 while\n");
printf("3 do while\n");
scanf("%d",&opc);
switch(opc){
    case 1:{
        for(i=1;i<=fibo;i++){
        c=a+b;
        a=b;
        b=c;    
        printf("%d ",a);}
        break;
    }
```

la idea es que si pido los primeros cinco numeros que serian 1,1,2,3,5
tambien imprima 5,3,2,1,1
de antemano muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Como veo que lo vas tener que hacer de varias formas (`for`, `do-while`, `while`...) he hecho una pequeña modificación del código que ya tienes hecho.

Una forma sencilla de hacerlo sería crear un `array` con la misma longitud (número de índices) que el valor de la variable `fibo`, que es el número que ha introducido el usuario por teclado.

> Por ejemplo:
>
> Si el usuario te dice que quiere obtener la sucesión de fibonacci
>   hasta el número `5`, guardamos el número `5` (nth posición en la secuencia) en la variable `fibo` y
>   crearíamos el array `sucesion[fibo]` que tendría longitud `5`.

Luego para cada iteración del bucle añades el número correspondiente de la sucesión en dicho array y posteriormente lo imprimes. Primero de forma normal y luego recorriendo el array del revés.

```
printf("Cuantos numeros de fibonacci necesitas?: ");
scanf("%d", &fibo);

int sucesion[fibo];

    for(i = 0; i < fibo; i++) {
        c = a + b;
        a = b;
        b = c;    
        sucesion[i] = a;
    }

    printf("Sucesión normal: "); //=> 1 1 2 3 5
    for (i = 0; i < fibo; i++) {
        printf("%d ", sucesion[i]);
    }

    printf("\nSucesión inversa: "); //=> 5 3 2 1 1
    for (i = fibo - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        printf("%d ", sucesion[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Calcula los términos en una función…

```
// Calcula el índice-esimo término de la sucesión de Fibonacci
int fib(int indice)
{
    int resultado = 0;
    if (indice == 0 || indice == 1)
        resultado = indice;
    else
        resultado = fib(indice - 1) + fib(indice - 2);

    return resultado;
}
```

… y llama a la función con índices descendentes:

```
int main(void)
{
    int fibo = 0;
    printf("cuantos numeros de fibonacci necesitas?\n");
    scanf("%d",&fibo);

    for (; fibo; --fibo)
        printf("%d ", fib(fibo));

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY/PTsMwDIfPzVNYRUOpWBHlGjZehEtwUrDUOSh/uGx79uKmGhucLP/sT/6M/QfiPN8R41Sch5eUHYXHz71SxBlGetdLJXaEvlNH1Sxt9KlM2boAO3gyko2g1xXYSQKnE1zboVNNc0usI8H8lPy/2Xqwor2Q8PA3ee6MUgLkEvlqYdR51T1YYv0dyP2aCn2R/IoSjLrFYjmHBFwOPkqVr5cttogE7NEnyja9vnErx5qElgXauHZ7v6xVgTFE0KZiBvq@5vLI5cLGQbut4nVy6ywi53keBvUD)</kbd>.